# PHP DOMXPath extract href of anchor inside a td

Tags: php, domxpath

Using PHP DOMXPath I need to get the "href" of an anchor that is contained inside a td.
I already able to get all the correct xPath to reach the td and i can get the text inside but i cant understand how can i extract the anchor.
For my other needed i must extract all tr as first step so my current code is below:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$trList = $xpath->query('//div[@id="main_content"]/table/tr/td/table[3]/tr[2]/td/table/tr');
$rowToSkip = 1;
foreach($trList as $rowNum => $row){        
        if($rowNum <= $rowToSkip){
            continue;
        }
        $cols = $row->childNodes;
        $dataList[($rowNum-$rowToSkip)]['number'] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", strip_tags($cols->item(2)->nodeValue));
}
```

how can i retrieve the href?

i also try with

$cols->item(2)->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->nodeValue

but with no luck

Below The HTML sample that is exacly the same as the original one:

```
<div id="main_content">
<table class="wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="breadcrumb">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="breadcrumb">
                                <a href="" class="breadcrumb">head link</a>
                                <a href="" class="breadcrumb">head link</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                <div><img src="space.gif" width="1" height="7" alt="" border="0"></div>                    
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" >test</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                <div><img width="1" height="32" border="0" alt="" src="space.gif"></div>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" >test 02</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td nowrap="nowrap" colspan="8">header col 1</td>
                                            <td nowrap="nowrap" colspan="5">header col 2</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td nowrap="nowrap">
                                                <a href="" >test col 0</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">
                                                <a href="" >test col 1</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">test col 2</td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">
                                                <a href="" >test col 3</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">
                                                <a href="" >test col 4</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">
                                                <a href="" >test col 5</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">test col 6</td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">test col 7</td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">test col 8</td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">test col 9</td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">test col 10</td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">test col 11</td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap">test col 12</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 0</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" style="background-color:red">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 1 this is needed column</a>                                                    
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 2</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 3</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 4</a>
                                            </td>
                                           <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 5</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 6</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 7</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 8</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 9</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 10</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 11</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td  nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1">
                                                <a href="" >detail info col 12</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is the html a reduced or exact version (meaning *the one a-tag under id xy*)? If the latter you could target the a-tag directly without explicitly *counting* the table and rows.

Comment: Something like: `$xpath->query('//*[@id="main_content"]//@href');`

Comment: @Yoshi is an extract of the page where I've dozen blocks with same table structure inside the div. I need to extract exactly this path because inside the page there are dozen links.. sadly this is the only way to target the correct one

Comment: Ok, is the double table (close the the final a-tag) deliberate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the structure you posted, the following outputs the href-value:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTMLFile('input.html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = '//*[@id="main_content"]/table/tr/td/table[3]/tr[2]/td/table/tr[position() >= 3]/td[2]/a';

$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    /** @var $node DOMElement */
    var_dump(
        $node->getAttribute('href'), // the href-attribute value
        $node->nodeValue // the inner text
    );
}
```

Comment: ok, this work but i can't retrieve the text that i get in my example (the numer "123456") retrived by dataList[($rowNum-$rowToSkip)]['number'] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", strip_tags($cols->item(2)->nodeValue)); in this way.. probably i miss something..

Comment: Ok, missed that. So you want the href-attribute value and the inner text value?

Comment: with the new xPath i get all column links, i need only one specific column, i update the example with a complete full page with only one row. This is the cut and past of page with only column name removed.  I need the column called "<a href="" >detail info col 1 this is needed column</a>         " Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: This last query seem exactly the xPath generated by chrome.. with this query i can get only the first line value.. i miss something?

Comment: @Marco I'm confused, the code selects exactly the a-tag you want and shows how to access the href attribute and the inner text. What do you mean by *"... only the first line value..."*?

Comment: Sorry I not explain correctly my needed. I have a table full of line that are similar to line inside my  example. I need to extract the information from column that i selected in the example (the column called "detail info col 1 this is needed column") but for each line! not only for the   first one, I can have even 200 rows in the table.

Comment: @Marco So the table directly containing the relevant tr, includes multiple rows, and for each you want the a-tag? ... Updated again, hope it's the correct one this time ;)